# Remove series of Duplicated Values

Tags: r, excel, dplyr

I've combined multiple excel sheets to one data frame but some of the values in stock_code column duplicates, for example: X company has values from 01-01-2009 to 31-12-2020, but the values in this range duplicates: (because at least two excel files have the same values for the same company)

```
> head(data,3)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
   tarih             stock_code       adj_close_price
  <dttm>              <chr>                <dbl>
1  2020-03-31 00:00:00 X                 2.87
2  2020-03-30 00:00:00 X               2.69
3  2020-03-27 00:00:00 X                 2.69
> tail(data,3)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
          tarih        stock_code       adj_close_price
         <dttm>          <chr>           <dbl>
1 2009-01-06 00:00:00  X                0.136
2  2009-01-05 00:00:00 X                0.129
3  2009-01-02 00:00:00 X               0.124
```

It seems fine, it goes from 2009 to 2020, then again, it shows the same values from 2009 to 2020 (as shows on the top).

I couldn't filter it since I don't want to remove the whole company but I only want to remove the duplicated **range** of the company.

Here's how I merged the files, maybe I should have added a condition to avoid some kind of duplicated values?

```
xlsx_files <- c("düzelt1.xlsx",
                "düzelt2.xlsx",
                "düzelt3.xlsx",
                "düzelt4.xlsx",
                "düzelt5.xlsx",
                "düzelt6.xlsx",
                "düzelt7.xlsx",
                "düzelt8.xlsx")

dataframes &lt;- lapply(xlsx_files, function(x) 
    read_excel(path = paste0("~/weekly_stock/", x)))

df <- do.call("rbind", dataframes)

tail(df)

files <- list.files(path = "~/weekly_stock", pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = T)

weekly_stock <- sapply(files, read_excel, simplify=FALSE) %>% 
    bind_rows(.id = "id")
```

Thanks and appreciating your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct` to keep only the unique values of `tarih` for each `stock_code`.

```
library(dplyr)

weekly_stock <- sapply(files, read_excel, simplify=FALSE) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "id") %>%
  distinct(stock_code, tarih, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try dplyr::distinct()
generic example below:

```
stock.data<- data.frame(stock =c("A","B","C","A","A"), date=c("2009","2009","2009","2010","2009"),price=c(20,30,40,50,20))

stock.data %>% distinct()
```